# Xcode 11.3.1 Embedded binaries section not found

Tags: xcode, react-native, binaries, embedded-binary

I'm using Xcode 11.3.1 on a React Native project.

I'm supposed to add a framework on the Embedded binaries section in General tab but this section does not show up.

Thanks for explanation

Comment: Update your question with what you are seeing in the General tab and the type of Xcode project you created. I noticed in Xcode 11.3.1 the Embedded Binaries section is called Frameworks, Libraries, and Embedded Content.